# Developing an app in local environment

Tags: facebook, localhost

I am creating an app on my work's server, which is using SVN. It's a real pain in the ass to commit & deploy every time I want to test something, instead of just being able to use my localhost environment.

Which I am sure is a possibility, I just can't find it. That leading to my question:

How do I set up my app so I can test on my localhost, and still use Facebook Social Graph/OAuth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a server alias in your apache config like this:

```
# local host
ServerName your-site.localhost

# alias
ServerAlias your-site.com
```

Then add the host to your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 your-site.com
```

This will route all your requests to your-site.com to localhost. I use this method for developing Facebook apps, pages and external sites that need to be on the *auth domain* I've set up in Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

I do it this way,
Set up the url of my app in Facebook as : http://**localhost**.example.com/appnameorwhatever.
This works for all sorts of apps, meaning page tab, canvas app etc.
Graph api/Oauth everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I went to app settings, and under "website," I set the "Mobile Site URL" to `http://localhost`. That way requests from both the regular site and from localhost are allowed.

Note: I was only using the JS SDK to develop FB connections for a website.